# Determine if .Net core console application is running in user interactive mode

Tags: .net-core

Is it possible to determine if a .Net core console application is running in user interactive mode?

In previous versions of .Net it was possible to test `Environment.UserInteractive` to see if the user had access to the application. This doesn't seem to exist in .Net core.

Comment: Currently it does exist. But looks like it returns true even if running from WindowsService. https://github.com/PeterKottas/DotNetCore.WindowsService/issues/69

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The problem that .NET Core faces more than classic .NET Framework is how "user interactive" is defined. Even on "classic" .NET, the `Environment.UserInteractive` feels hacky as it relies on a [system API call to query user object flags](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms683238(v=vs.85).aspx) and tests for a flag described as [`Window station has visible display surfaces`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms686892(v=vs.85).aspx). It is unclear what exactly this should semantically mean on a GUI-less windows nano server that you use to run commands from.

My suggestion is to determine the exact use case on what you want to test. You could for instance test if the attached input and output streams are redirected using `Console.IsOutputRedirected` and `Console. IsInputRedirected`. On non-windows systems, a call to `isatty()` could be made but that isn't currently available as .NET API (you'd have to write the PInvoke code). If you want to determine if you are running as a windows service, TopShelf [checks if the process has been started by the service host](https://github.com/Topshelf/Topshelf/blob/956325c8104136af7e8f8fc708b6237668d1c55c/src/Topshelf/Runtime/Windows/WindowsHostEnvironment.cs#L142-L147). Another approach would be to add additional arguments for specific use cases - e.g. add and check for `--noninteractive` when you want to run a tool from a script.

Comment: Simple always rules - pass in parameters to govern the state, like you said.

Answer (score 3):

To complement [Martin Ullrich's helpful answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45408297/45375):

**If you're willing to define *user-interactive* as *runs in a console/terminal window visible to the current user***, you can use the following approach (C#), which should work on all supported platforms:

Note: *Visible* means visible *in principle*, i.e., can be made visible by the user if currently obscured or minimized.

```cs
using System;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

namespace net.same2u.pg
{
  static class Program
  {
    // P/Invoke declarations for Windows.
    [DllImport("kernel32.dll")] static extern IntPtr GetConsoleWindow();
    [DllImport("user32.dll")] static extern bool IsWindowVisible(IntPtr hWnd);

    // Indicates if the current process is running:
    //  * on Windows: in a console window visible to the user.
    //  * on Unix-like platform: in a terminal window, which is assumed to imply
    //    user-visibility (given that hidden processes don't need terminals).
    public static bool HaveVisibleConsole()
    {
      return RuntimeInformation.IsOSPlatform(OSPlatform.Windows) ?
                    IsWindowVisible(GetConsoleWindow())
                    :
                    Console.WindowHeight > 0;
    }

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
      Console.WriteLine($"Running in visible console? {HaveVisibleConsole()}");
    }
  }
}
```

Note:

- On Windows, all console-mode applications *always* run in a console window, whether that window is visible or not; the P/Invoke function declarations check if the console window (`GetConsoleWindow()`) - if any - associated with the current process is a visible window (`IsWindowVisible()`, on the current user's desktop).
- On Unix-like platforms, non-GUI applications fundamentally don't need a terminal window to run, and launching such an application from a GUI app, for instance, does not involve a terminal. Therefore, the assumption is that if a terminal window is *present at all*, it implies that that window is *visible*; `Console.WindowHeight` only contains a positive value if a terminal window is present.

Answer (score 1):

Another option is to check a process session id: for services it's always 0. So you can use the following snippet:

```cs
// Environment.UserInteractive is not working on NET Core 3.1
if (Process.GetCurrentProcess().SessionId != 0) 
{
    service.RunAsConsole(args);
}
else
{
    ServiceBase.Run(service);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This probably will be fixed in some future version of .NET Core (maybe 5.0):

https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/issues/770 and 
https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/pull/1234

Meanwhile see other answers (e.g. `Console.IsInputRedirected` should work for detecting Windows Service context).

Answer (score 0):

Here's a modern .NET 5-compatible way to implement a cross-platform `IsInteractive` property for a console app:

```
public static bool IsInteractive => Environment.UserInteractive &&
    (OperatingSystem.IsWindows() ||
    !(Console.IsInputRedirected && Console.IsOutputRedirected && Console.IsErrorRedirected));
```

This is based on [Martin Ullrich's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45408297/1882616) and on information from dotnet's [issue #770](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/issues/770#issuecomment-564700467), [issue #66530](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/issues/66530#issuecomment-1065854289), and [ConsolePal.Unix.cs](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/blob/main/src/libraries/System.Console/src/System/ConsolePal.Unix.cs#L674). On Windows, it trusts the `Environment.UserInteractive` property. On non-Windows, that property always returns true, so we'll fallback to whether all the standard console streams are redirected (like [when cron launches a process](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73261754/1882616)).

For simplicity, you could even omit the Windows-specific checks like this:

```
public static bool IsInteractive =>
    !(Console.IsInputRedirected && Console.IsOutputRedirected && Console.IsErrorRedirected);
```

When a console app is run as a Windows service, all of its standard streams are redirected, so this will return false (i.e., not interactive).