# DLL project - Knowing which environment had called it ? (web/win/cmd)

Tags: c#, .net

Say I have a PDF-Factory dll which generates PDFs.

Besides referencing `System.Web` and check for `HttpContext.Current == null` ,

**Question:**

Is there any more precise way of knowing if a function in the DLL was called through `Web`/`Console`/`Gui` context ?

Comment: Just don't use an oracle, the caller always knows.  Add a parameter.

Comment: How about `Process.GetCurrentProcess().ProcessName`? For IIS it would be `w3wp.exe` and for console it would be the name of the exe file

Comment: Out of curiosity. Why do you need to know that?

Comment: @Steve we had a pdf problem timeout , and when I was about to set thread execution timeout for the web , it turned out  actually that it was called through Gui. And then I've asked myself ( for learning purpose) , how can I know if it's web/cmd/web ...

Comment: @Vikhram If that cmd called the PDF method in its code , then it should be CMD.

Comment: I would give the client the control over this parameter then. Let it set the appropriate timeout or add some kind of configuration to make your library adapt to different environments.

Comment: @Steve that pdf library doesn't support timeout. it was the asp.net thread timeout exception.

Comment: You can also try to dynamically load some type from `System.Web` using something like `Type.GetType("System.Web.HttpContext", false, true)` and conclude it's a Web environment when it doesn't return `null`

Comment: @haim770 yes. I wrote _a similar_ approach in my question :-)

Comment: I must say that I disagree of "sending a variable indicating which env". We should keep DRY. and if a source of information can be concluded from one source , then no other source should be created. Caller can be wrong ( copy paste). if that information can be gotten inside the dll , then it should be done there.

Comment: @RoyiNamir, Not exactly, my approach would not require you to reference the actual `System.Web` assembly. It dynamically checks for its existence using names only

Comment: And `AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies().Any(a => a.GetName().Name == "System.Web")` might work as well...

Comment: @haim770 Yes. I agree , I said "similar". Yours is a better approach. ( but won't show GUI vs CMD). it will only detect web vs not-web

Comment: @Vikhram You can load `System.Web` but not to use it and then my original solution would work. and I don't understand why you keep providing the GUI app which is calling CMD app. if the CMD app called pdf code , then it should be recognized as CMD. if the GUI app called that dll , then it should be the GUI.

Comment: @Vikhram It is possible . Both you and I know it. It's just that I want to find a better way of knowing it.

Comment: So you've got automated test runners that simulate each environment that you're magically testing for? Because if not and you're just using standard test runners, it leaves a lot of code either untested or only manually tested...

Comment: You're also limiting yourself for future use. What if someone finds a new environment to call your code from (e.g. imagine you'd written this before UWP came along) and *none* of your current behaviours are appropriate?

Comment: @haim770 As people said here , you can add reference assemblies and still not using them . so your solution might fail.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only thing i could think of is using [system.environment.userinteractive](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.environment.userinteractive?view=netframework-4.7.2) to check if your code is running in a context that allows user-interaction and therefore is a GUI-app and not a web-app.

Answer (score 0):

After using the above suggestions to determine web or not, check out this post:

[How to tell if there is a console](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6408588/how-to-tell-if-there-is-a-console)